# How to reset mat slide toggle that gets initial value from an API call in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have the following mat-slide-toggle, where `item` comes from an API call.

```
<mat-slide-toggle [checked]="item.status" [disabled]="clicked" (change)="onItemChange(item); clicked = true"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

When a user toggles this switch, a POST call is sent to change the item's status. If the call fails however, I need to reset this toggle to its original position so the UI stays in sync with the true value of status. I have tried the following to do this.

```
onItemChange(item: MyItem) {
  this.myService.changeItemStatus(this.accountId, item.id).pipe(
      catchError((e) => {
        item.status = !item.status;
        return e;
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        this.clicked = false;
      })
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
    });
  }
}
```

However, the toggle does not reset even though the `catchError` block is definitely being executed and this also seems to prevent the code in the `finalize` block from running which should re-enable the toggle after the call has finished.

Comment: Can you try to console the value of `item.status` after being assigned new value? also check the type of value

Comment: Looks like the value isn't changing from the original once the toggle is clicked. So if `item.status` is false, doing a console.log inside the `catchError` block of the `onItemChange` function shows that it's still false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. I additionally passed `$event` to my `onItemChange()` function and was able to access the `checked` property directly in the TS code.

HTML

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(checked)]="item.status" [disabled]="clicked" (change)="onItemChange(item, $event); clicked = true"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

TS

```
onItemChange(item: MyItem, event) {
    this.myService.changeItemStatus(this.accountId, item.id).pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        event.source.checked = !event.source.checked;
        return of();
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        this.clicked = false;
      })
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped.

Comment: Excellent, also works when using error: () => in the subscribe like so:      error: () => {
        event.source.checked = !event.source.checked;